# how to clear laravel Undefined variable error

Tags: laravel

I'm using a variable called `$members` form `index()` method. but I can able to get that values in the home page. please help me to clear that error

**model**

```
public function index()
    {
        $members = Member::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('home', compact('members'))
        ->with('i',(request()->input('page',1)-1)*5);
    }
```

**view**

```
 @foreach ($members as $member)
    <tr>
        <td>$member->image</td>
        <td>$member->name</td>
        <td>$member->nikename</td>
        <td>$member->role</td>

    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('members', 'MemberController');
```

**Error:**

```
Undefined variable: members (View: C:\Users\System41\Desktop\laravel_lan\resources\views\home.blade.php)
```

Comment: check if you have the same route twice in ```web.php``` ..make sure you use the right controller and method for the route

Comment: What happens when you  return view('home', compact('members')); only this

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. However, if you want to display the actual value of $member do this: ```<td>{{$member->name}}</td>```

Comment: route are u `Route::resource('members', 'MemberController');`

Comment: your `Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');` route may be pointing the same home view. how are you currently trying to go to the home view? `/home` or `/members`?

Comment: but i make a `resource` for the home. if i make a `members.blade.php` that allso get the same error in `return view('members', compact('members'))`

Comment: Can you do `dd($members );` in your controller and provide data? @kealaxshan

Comment: what is your current url? `/home` or `/members`?

Comment: `/home` is my current url

Comment: @kealaxshan the method `index` in your question above ^  is it in HomeController or MemeberController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you guys i got solution

i have to change some thing in `HomeController`
that are

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Member;

public function index()
    {
         $members = Member::latest()->paginate(5);
         return view('home', compact('members'))
        ->with('i',(request()->input('page',1)-1)*5);

    }
```

**route**

```
 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
   Route::resource('members', 'MemberController');
```

Comment: that's a bizarre solution. you should have used the resource `MemberController`. I think your `HomeController` is not a resource controller. And it's normally used for base functionalities.

Comment: What change was it? I am unable to spot the difference.